# Can't build neo4j/spatial

Tags: maven, neo4j, spatial

Running:

```
git clone git://github.com/neo4j/spatial.git
cd spatial
mvn clean compile
```

yields the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project neo4j-spatial: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]
```

Do I have the wrong version of something?

**UPDATE:** I can not replicate this error on other machines. So, I consider the issue moot. The problem must be a path variable or some such.

Comment: Do you have Java 7 installed?

Comment: I use Java 6 since neo4j complains with seven. Does some dependency require 7?

Comment: You problem here is caused by you not having windows 7 installed, however I cannot tell you if `spatial` absolutely requires it.